# Detecting Conditional formatting within a range

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to set up a spreadsheet on excel that works a lot of calculations out but is also allowing for variables within it (i.e the team numbers change sometimes).

In this case I have 4 separate teams. Each team has it's own default conditional formatting which will set a default colour for that team. I've done this by just detecting if the cell is blank.

[Example of teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NuRv.png)

As you can see the default colours are blue and orange for shown 2 teams.

The issue I have is when someone copies & pastes from Orange to Blue team it takes on the formatting of said team. For example if I copy and paste from Orange team where it says "COURSE" in yellow into the blue team, when I delete the word "COURSE" it should default back to blue but as it has been copied from Orange it defaults back to orange.

I have managed to set the following which resets the formatting back to its original blue default (This is currently done from a button press for debug purposes).

```
Range(MyRange1).Select


Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=LEN(TRIM(D2))=0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
    .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

My issue is eventually I want to link this to a worksheet change to allow for copy & pasting. But every time it runs it creates a duplicate version of the conditional formatting within the rules.

So I need to delete any other instances of the condition that previously exists, otherwise overtime they will stack up.

I know it's going to be an IF/THEN statement but for the life of me I cannot think how to test for it.

I have severe writer's block at the moment so I really hope this makes sense!

Comment: Just paste the values or perform a direct value transfer; leave the CFR behind.

Answer (score 1):

This will cycle through all the conditional formats applied in `MyRange1` and delete any that are not priority one.

```
For Each f In MyRange1.FormatConditions
    If f.Priority <> 1 Then f.Delete
Next
```

Sorry, just noticed that you use `MyRange1` as the range address, so you'd use:

```
For Each f In Range(MyRange1).FormatConditions
    If f.Priority <> 1 Then f.Delete
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just delete the old conditions and then reinstate them every time you copy and paste?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)

Range("A1:A100").Select

With Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
End With

Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=LEN(TRIM(D2))=0"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
    .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah I think that is what I will have to do. As there are multiple Conditional formats within the range.